# Pass CSS class to Angular Library

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-cdk

I am creating a library using angular CDK for custom modal. I want the application which would use the library to pass the CSS class name with other configuration for the modal window. So that I can apply the class like this in the library.

```
  this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(modalConfig.overlayContainerClass);
```

I can see the class is applied to the element but no class present.

```
<div class="cdk-overlay-container overlay-material-design-theme mat-typography custom">
```

I have defined this in the application component CSS file.

```
.custom{
  width: 100%;
}
```

The question is how the CSS which is present in the application component would be accessible to library component?

Comment: the `custom` class should be defined in a file that's not subject to the encapsulation rules. Usually that's the global styles.scss file in the root folder. Or in a file that is imported in there if you want more structure.

Comment: please also mark the actual answer as the correct one so other people will know what the solution was easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For css classes to work that way you have to put them in a place where view encapsulation is not present.

The place for that is usually in the `src/styles.scss`.

If you want more structure you can have them in another scss file that `src/styles.scss` imports.